# CMake FindCURL finds curl but doesn't set CURL_LIBRARIES and CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS

Tags: c++, curl, cmake

I have build the libcurl from source with cmake and installed to /usr/local/ and I used `find_package(CURL 7.88.1 EXACT REQUIRED)` in my project's main CMakeLists.txt. It find CURL with 7.88.1 version, however, when I want to print `CURL_LIBRARIES` and `CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS` in CMakeLists.txt prints nothing. Furthermore, I tried to link the libcurl with `CURL::libcurl` which is set in `CURLTargets.cmake` still I can't see it linked shared to my binary.

```
find_package(CURL 7.88.1 EXACT REQUIRED)

message("curl libs: ${CURL_LIBRARIES}")
message("curl dirs: ${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

...

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
        ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${RAPIDJSON_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${ZeroMQ_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
                        ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
                        spdlog::spdlog
                        CURL::libcurl
                        ${CURL_LIBRARIES}
                        ${ZeroMQ_LIBRARY})
```

output:

```
-- Found CURL: /usr/local/lib/cmake/CURL/CURLConfig.cmake (found suitable exact version "7.88.1")  
curl libs: 
curl dirs:
```

cmake reference: [FindCURL](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCURL.html)

OS: Windows subsystem linux Ubuntu 20.04

CMake Version: 3.19.8

Comment: @user253751 Unfortunately, it doesn't see.

Comment: @user253751 I am able to see libcurl is linked to my binary with ```ldd``` as you said and stated in [FindCURL](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCURL.html) under section ```IMPORTED Targets```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the [`FindCURL` module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCURL.html), when CURL is installed with cmake, loads CURL's own cmake config instead of doing whatever it normally does, so it doesn't set these variables.

However, in both cases you should be able to add `CURL::libcurl` as a library with `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} CURL::libcurl)`. This will automatically set the include directories and add the library and anything else that's needed.